# Is it agains the convention to use `Vue.nextTick` in the Vuex mutation? May it break something?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

As far as I know a mutation in Vuex should be synchronous. `Vuex.nextTick` ends up being asynchronous if I understand it correctly. Does it make it agains the convention to use it in the mutation then? Could it break something?
I have tried doing it this way and it seemed to work fine, but   I haven't tried going back to previous state with Dev Tools for example.

Just to let You know: I use `nextTick` to postpone some sorting to avoid doing it unnecessarily multiple times. Maybe You have some other solution to that issue? I know I could use an action istead of a mutation, but I wanted to change some actions I already have into mutations as it seems to be a better option for me, but they use this piece of code.

Comment: Your intuition looks correct, it seems weird to call asynchronous code in a mutation. Why using an action for this is not a solution for you? It would be the best idea for this kind of trick...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have already used actions for that, but wanted to change them into mutations. Maybe I could just split the code and move just some parts of it into mutations and leave this one as action for example. I'll have to check if that's possible.

Comment: But why moving to a mutation if as an action it works fine?
If it's a reason of clarity, of course you could split it up into multiple actions / mutations. But the async part should remain in the actions! :)

Comment: @Kapcash, clarity is one reason, but I also though about future ability to undo or redo some changes based on mutations. Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `nextTick` in a mutation effectively moves the code outside the mutation, so you'll get errors in strict mode and the Devtools can't track the changes.

Also, `nextTick` won't run until after the next round of rendering, so you're going to be rendering multiple times.

If possible use a getter for the sorted list instead.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I thought about using a getter, but it seemed to be called multiple times, even when uncessary. That's why I decided to introduce manual calling for sorting and just keeping the sorted list in the `state`. Maybe there's some way to avoid uncessary getter calls? Or some in-between solution like having a variable `sortingRequired`? I though about using some `watch` but as far as I know there's nothing like that in the Vuex itself or when defining a store and I'd have to do it in some component or "main.js".

Comment: @kcpr `getters` work just like `computed` properties. The cached value will be invalidated as soon as a dependency changes but calculating the new value is lazy and will only happen if something tries to use that value. One potential problem is that it might be invalidated in cases where nothing important has actually changed, maybe that's the problem you're having. Trickery involving a `sortingRequired` property and a watcher might be a legitimate approach in extreme cases. The composition API makes that slightly easier.